# Is there an equivalent of the Show typeclass for Data.Text?

Tags: haskell, text, typeclass

Everyone knows `Show`.  But what about:

```
class ShowText a where
  showText :: a -> Text
```

I can't find this anywhere.  Why?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-show/0.3.5.1/doc/html/Text-Show-ByteString.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The library [text-show](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show) exists now and solves exactly this problem.

**Update (2016 Feb 12)**

The `show` function provided in the [basic-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/basic-prelude) library also renders straight to text:

```
show :: Show a => a -> Text
```

`basic-prelude` also has fewer dependencies than `text-show`. If you want to use `basic-prelude`, save yourself compilation headaches by adding the following to the top of your source file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
```

Comment: In both basic-prelude and classy-prelude there is [tshow](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.23/hoogle?q=tshow)

Answer (score 15):

The problem with creating the Text directly is you still need to know the overall size of the strict Text block before filling it in. You can do better with a Builder scheme and using Data.Text.Lazy. Dan Doel does this in bytestring-show, but I'm not aware of an equivalent for Text.

Comment: Speaking of read/show functions... Can a pair of ("read function which may fail","show function") for a given datatype be turned into a Prism from Control.Lens ?

Comment: Yep! You need the ability to run the `Read` and get out whether it matched or not, which was only added recently to base though.

Answer (score 5):

For the particular case of `Int` values, here's the code to convert them into strict `Text` values without using `Strings` in an intermediate stage:

```
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder (toLazyText)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.Int (decimal)

showIntegral :: Integral a => a -> T.Text
showIntegral = toStrict. toLazyText . decimal
```

Module `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.RealFloat` offers similar functionality for floating point values.

With these we can define a our own version of the `Show` typeclass:

```
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder (toLazyText)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.Int (decimal)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.RealFloat (realFloat)

class ShowText a where
    showText :: a -> Text

instance ShowText Int where
    showText = toStrict . toLazyText . decimal

instance ShowText Float where
    showText = toStrict . toLazyText . realFloat
```

Then we can start adding more instances (one for tuples would be useful for example).

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to write your own function piggybacking off `Show`:

```
showText :: Show a => a -> Text
showText = pack . show
```

Comment: Does this have a performance hit?  i.e., aren't I creating a big `String` then converting it to a `Text`, rather than creating the `Text` directly?

Comment: Don't you loose all gains of using Data.Text this way? You use Text mainly because of `String`'s prefromance issues - and this way you throw all gains off...

Comment: Given that the `Show` typeclass basically only requires `show :: a -> String`, there is no way to implement `showText` without going through a String. The `tshow` functions in basic and classy prelude are also implemented like this.

Answer (score 1):

In both [basic-prelude](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.23/basic-prelude-0.6.1.1/BasicPrelude.html#v:tshow) and [classy-prelude](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.23/classy-prelude-1.2.0.1/ClassyPrelude.html#v:tshow) there is a `tshow` function now.

```
tshow :: Show a => a -> Text
```

If you're using the standard prelude, try the [text-show library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show).